# install vscode extension on WSL or EMR from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to force install from the command line. Obviously, this is after opening WSL or ssh tunnel opened from VSCode Windows side. Tried below:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-82-184 bin]$ pwd
/home/hadoop/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/bin
[hadoop@ip-172-31-82-184 bin]$ ./code --install-extensions VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
./code: line 12: ./node: No such file or directory
```

Kind regards

Comment: is there a reason you want to install VSCode on the WSL side rather than the Windows side - when you should install it on the Windows side according to the WSL VSCode extension instructions? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_installation

Comment: I have installed on Windows. It's just that I want make sure the extensions get installed on the WSL or EMR side, which often fails from VSCode GUI.

Comment: ah, I see. Did you follow https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_managing-extensions to install extensions in WSL? how did it fail from the GUI? From your error message it looks Node cannot be found - is it installed in WSL?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's a simple answer. Yeh!
Just guessed & it was there all along. Auto installed by ssh-tool itself.